# Hive FAILED: Parse Exception line 3:39 mismatched input

Tags: hiveql

Im trying to make a query that will check if there is any row which has a **salary that is 10000 higher than the salary for that department** but when I try to run it I get this Error:

> FAILED: ParseException line 3:39 mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting ) near '''' in expression specification

this is the query Im using

```
set AVERAGES ='SELECT ROLE, AVG(AnnualSalary) From Salaries GROUP BY ROLE';


   SELECT ROLE, AVG(AnnualSalary) FROM Salaries 
   GROUP BY ROLE, AnnualSalary HAVING AnnualSalary > ('${hiveconf:AVERAGES}' + 10000);
```

Comment: why are you using variable for storing query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Hive does not support storing the query result into variable.

You can use window function to achieve this.

```
select * from 
    ( select *, 
            avg(AnnualSalary) over(partition by ROLE) role_avg 
            from 
                Salaries
    ) a 
where 
AnnualSalary > role_avg+10000
```